# How to point an equation to a curve

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            black,              
            xlabel={\textit{potential}},
            ylabel={\textit{cost}},
            xlabel style={below right},
            ylabel style={above center},
            xmax=5,
            ymax=2,
            axis lines=middle,
            enlargelimits
            ]

\addplot [mark=none, red, thick] {exp(-x)}
         node [pos=1, pin=500:{%
              \color{black}%
              $\exp(\frac{z_i-z_j}{2\sigma})$%
              }] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need to place the formula `$\exp(\frac{z_i-z_j}{2\sigma})$` pointing towards the middle of the exponential curve. Thx!

Comment: N.B. You should not use math-mode for italics. I've revised your code for this, and also to remove the scroll-bars, but without changing much else.

Answer (score 5):

You can control the position of nodes most easily, in this case, by using the co-ordinate system of the plot itself to define co-ordinates/nodes, and drawing them in the normal TiKZ style.

**Source**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            black,              
            xlabel={\textit{potential}},
            ylabel={\textit{cost}},
            xlabel style={below right},
            ylabel style={above center},
            xmax=5,
            ymax=2,
            axis lines=middle,
            enlargelimits
            ]

    \addplot [mark=none, red, thick] {exp(-x)};

    \coordinate (P) at (axis cs:1,{exp(-1)});
    \node (label) at (axis cs:3,{1+exp(-1)}) {$\exp(\frac{z_i-z_j}{2\sigma})$};
    \draw [red!50!black, thick, dashed, ->, shorten >=2pt] (label) -- (P);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image: Plot with a label and an arrow]

Answer (score 5):

This is just one possibility.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[grid=both,  %grid=none
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            black,              
            xlabel={$potential$},
            ylabel={$cost$},
            xlabel style={below right},
            ylabel style={above center},
            xmax=5,
            ymax=2,
            axis lines=middle,
            %restrict y to domain=-7:12,
            enlargelimits,
            domain=-.5:5
            ]
\addplot[mark=none, red, thick] {exp(-x)} coordinate[pos=0.3] (aux);
\node[anchor=south west, text=black] (a) at (axis cs:2,0.5) {$\exp(\frac{z_i-z_j}{2\sigma})$};
\draw (aux)--(a.west);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `$potential$` --> `potential` and `$cost$` --> `cost`.

Comment: The original had the dollar signs in it before my edit, this is not really Ignasi's fault.

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

% approximation to Euler's number
\def\PSEuler{2.71828182845904523536 }
% point on x-axis
\def\point{1.5 }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \psset{yunit = 2}
  \begin{pspicture}(-0.73,-0.27)(7.04,2.5)% found manually
    \psaxes[Dy = 0.5]{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-0.25)(5.5,2.3)[Potential,0][Cost,90]
    \psplot[linecolor = red]{-0.6}{5}{\PSEuler x neg exp}
    \psline{->}%
      (!\point 1 add \PSEuler \point neg 1 add exp)%
      (!\point \PSEuler \point neg exp)
    \uput[90](!\point 1 add \PSEuler \point neg 1 add exp)%
      {$\displaystyle \exp{\mkern -8mu}\left(\frac{z_{i} - z_{j}}{2\sigma}
       \right)$}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

A MetaPost solution, for whom it interests. The middle of a path is easily found with the [Metafun](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) format of MetaPost: it is `point .5 along curve` if `curve` is the name of the path. For MetaPost experts, here is the definition of the `along` binary operator in the Metafun format:

```
primarydef pct along pat = % also negative
    (arctime (pct * (arclength pat)) of pat) of pat
enddef ;
```

Metafun also defines a handy `function` macro which produces the curve associated to a function (or a parametric curve), which I used here. It also defines some macros to produce grids, but I find them awkward to handle, so I devised my own macro here, `gridlines`, inspired by the [`mfpic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfpic) package.

Since I do not like labels crisscrossed by grids or curves, I also defined a macro clearing the bounding box of each label, `clearlabel`.

To be processed with LuaLaTeX. (Needs version 2.10.1 of the `luamplib` package or higher.)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \mplibnumbersystem{double}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u := 1.25cm; v := 2.5cm;
    Xmin := -.75; Xmax := 5.4; Ymin := -.25; Ymax := 2.25;
    xmin := Xmin; xmax := 5; xstep := .05; ystep := .5;

    def gridlines (expr xmin, xmax, xstep)(expr ymin, ymax, ystep) =
      for i = ceiling(xmin/xstep) upto xmax div xstep:
        draw (i*xstep, ymin) -- (i*xstep, ymax) ;
      endfor 
      for j = ceiling(ymin/ystep) upto ymax div ystep:
        draw (xmin, j*ystep) -- (xmax, j*ystep);
      endfor
    enddef;

    vardef clearlabel@#(expr str, pos) =
      save pic; picture pic; pic = thelabel@#(str, pos);
      unfill boundingbox pic enlarged bp; draw pic
    enddef;

    beginfig(1);
      drawoptions(withcolor .8white);
      gridlines(Xmin*u, Xmax*u, u)(Ymin*v, Ymax*v, .5v);  
      drawoptions();
      drawarrow (Xmin*u, 0) -- (Xmax*u, 0); drawarrow (0, Ymin*v) -- (0, Ymax*v);
      path curve; 
      curve = function(2, "x", "exp -x", xmin, xmax, xstep) xyscaled (u, v);
      draw curve withcolor red;

      picture mylabel; 
      mylabel = thelabel("$\exp\!\Big(\dfrac{z_i-z_j}{2\sigma} \Big)$",
        .5(Xmax*u, Ymax*v));
      drawarrow center bbox mylabel -- point .5 along curve;
      unfill bbox mylabel; draw mylabel;
      for i = 1 upto 5:
        clearlabel.bot("$" & decimal i & "$", (i*u, 0));
      endfor;
      for j = .5 step .5 until 2:
        clearlabel.lft("$" & decimal j & "$", (0, j*v));
      endfor
      label.top("Potential", (Xmax*u, 0)); 
      label.lft("Cost", (0, Ymax*v));
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]