# How to plot only positive region in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I've got the following code here ([Drawing Sinusoids with Phase difference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239981/drawing-sinusoids-with-phase-difference)), but now I have the parameter 'time' on the x-axis, therefore I'm trying to have only the positive region but I'm having trouble in positioning the y-axis on the left keeping the x-axis in the middle.

[image: Potential, Current vs time]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}                           
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel={$time$},
    xlabel style={at={(1,0.5)},anchor=west},
    enlargelimits,
    ytick={-1, -0.5, 0.5, 1},
    yticklabels={},
    xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, ..., 6.28318},
    xticklabels={},
    clip=false]

\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=200, red, thick] {sin(x)};
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=200, blue, thick, dashed] {sin(x-2)};
\draw[dotted,black] (axis cs: 1.57,1.1) -- (axis cs: 1.57,0);
\draw[dotted,black] (axis cs: 3.57,1.1) -- (axis cs: 3.57,0);
\draw[dashed,black,<->] (axis cs: 1.57,1.1) --
   node[above,text=black,font=\footnotesize]{$\phi$} (axis cs: 3.57,1.1);
\coordinate (P) at (axis cs:1.5*pi,{sin(25)});
    \node (labelI) at (axis cs:2*pi,{1+sin(2*pi)}) {Current $(I)$};
    \draw [black, thick, dashed, ->, shorten >=2pt] (labelI) -- (P);
\coordinate (Q) at (axis cs:-1.85*pi,{sin(30)});
    \node (labelE) at (axis cs:-2*pi,{1+sin(2*pi)}) {Potential $(E)$};
    \draw [red!50!black, thick, dashed, ->, shorten >=2pt] (labelE) -- (Q);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Do you mean `axis x line = middle,axis y line=left,`? That said, if you want only the positive x-values, why not set the `domain` to start at zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it is sufficient to change the `domain` of the plotted functions.

Specifically, I changed `domain=-2*pi:2*pi` to `domain=0:2*pi`.

If you also don't want the extra length of the main axes, remove the `enlargelimits` option.

For my personal taste, I'd rather use a legend than arrows connecting the labels to the curves ;)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel={$time$},
    xlabel style={at={(1,0.5)},anchor=west},
    enlargelimits,
    ytick={-1, -0.5, 0.5, 1},
    yticklabels={},
    xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, ..., 6.28318},
    xticklabels={},
    clip=false,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    ]

\addplot[samples=200, red, thick] {sin(x)};
\addplot[samples=200, blue, thick, dashed] {sin(x-2)};
\draw[dotted,black] (axis cs: 1.57,1.1) -- (axis cs: 1.57,0);
\draw[dotted,black] (axis cs: 3.57,1.1) -- (axis cs: 3.57,0);
\draw[dashed,black,<->] (axis cs: 1.57,1.1) --
   node[above,text=black,font=\footnotesize]{$\phi$} (axis cs: 3.57,1.1);
\coordinate (P) at (axis cs:1.5*pi,{sin(25)});
    \node (labelI) at (axis cs:2*pi,{1+sin(2*pi)}) {Current $(I)$};
    \draw [black, thick, dashed, ->, shorten >=2pt] (labelI) -- (P);
\coordinate (Q) at (axis cs:1.33*pi,{-sin(120)});
    \node (labelE) at (axis cs:2*pi,{.5+sin(2*pi)}) {Potential $(E)$};
    \draw [red!50!black, thick, dashed, ->, shorten >=2pt] (labelE) -- (Q);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!  You've solved my problem and yes, I will put a legend, that was only a draft model of the graph.

Comment: You are welcome! remember also to [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up)/[accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) the answers that helped you the most ;)