# Adding Arrows and Text in tikz figure

Tags: pgfplots

I need your input on something again. 
I'm playing around with Tikzpicture and creating plots within the latex environment. I am trying to produce this graph (or something similar to this):

[image: Matlab figure I'm trying to simulate]

So my coding looks like this :

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=.4\textwidth,
    height=2.546667in,
    at={(0.924444in,0.586667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-40000,
    xmax=40000,
    xlabel={Amplitude},
    xmajorgrids,
    y dir=reverse,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=25,
    ylabel={Time (ns)},
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        -3  -3.166\\
        -12 -3.066\\
        -5  -2.966\\
        -7  -2.866\\
        -3  -2.766\\
        1   -2.666\\
        2   -2.566\\
        2   -2.466\\
        -3  -2.366\\
        4   -2.266\\
        11  -2.166\\
        17  -2.066\\
        26  -1.966\\
        27  -1.866\\
        33  -1.766\\
        40  -1.666\\
        45  -1.566\\
        62  -1.466\\
        79  -1.366\\
        118 -1.266\\
        177 -1.166\\
        271 -1.066\\
        365 -0.966\\
        461 -0.866\\
        550 -0.766\\
        697 -0.666\\
        696 -0.566\\
        341 -0.466\\
        -48 -0.366\\
        -154    -0.266\\
        346 -0.166\\
        1224    -0.066\\
        3545    0.034\\
        8141    0.134\\
        5706    0.234\\
        -13517  0.334\\
        -32768  0.434\\
        -32757  0.534\\
        -5532   0.634\\
        31936   0.734\\
        27398   0.834\\
        -4778   0.934\\
        -31155  1.034\\
        -32768  1.134\\
        -29306  1.234\\
        -13373  1.334\\
        7378    1.434\\
        19745   1.534\\
        16028   1.634\\
        2783    1.734\\
        -9033   1.834\\
        -10585  1.934\\
        -3993   2.034\\
        4236    2.134\\
        9595    2.234\\
        8116    2.334\\
        -5  2.434\\
        -8767   2.534\\
        -13127  2.634\\
        -9613   2.734\\
        -1335   2.834\\
        3584    2.934\\
        1860    3.034\\
        -3526   3.134\\
        -7376   3.234\\
        -6266   3.334\\
        -2515   3.434\\
        754 3.534\\
        2764    3.634\\
        2172    3.734\\
        111 3.834\\
        -1519   3.934\\
        -939    4.034\\
        2387    4.134\\
        6302    4.234\\
        7912    4.334\\
        6614    4.434\\
        3965    4.534\\
        1966    4.634\\
        983 4.734\\
        1345    4.834\\
        3181    4.934\\
        5065    5.034\\
        6111    5.134\\
        6588    5.234\\
        6479    5.334\\
        5663    5.434\\
        3664    5.534\\
        1552    5.634\\
        1225    5.734\\
        3003    5.834\\
        5123    5.934\\
        5499    6.034\\
        4764    6.134\\
        5309    6.234\\
        6647    6.334\\
        6216    6.434\\
        3636    6.534\\
        -39 6.634\\
        -4629   6.734\\
        -8524   6.834\\
        -7413   6.934\\
        3402    7.034\\
        18078   7.134\\
        24579   7.234\\
        15163   7.334\\
        -1527   7.434\\
        -10438  7.534\\
        -5921   7.634\\
        2441    7.734\\
        4618    7.834\\
        501 7.934\\
        -5571   8.034\\
        -8993   8.134\\
        -5972   8.234\\
        1988    8.334\\
        9817    8.434\\
        11042   8.534\\
        7945    8.634\\
        3777    8.734\\
        817 8.834\\
        736 8.934\\
        3093    9.034\\
        5387    9.134\\
        5015    9.234\\
        1367    9.334\\
        -2484   9.434\\
        -4851   9.534\\
        -5300   9.634\\
        -3905   9.734\\
        -573    9.834\\
        3137    9.934\\
        4689    10.034\\
        4243    10.134\\
        3046    10.234\\
        1868    10.334\\
        970 10.434\\
        672 10.534\\
        1349    10.634\\
        2254    10.734\\
        2264    10.834\\
        1533    10.934\\
        1043    11.034\\
        891 11.134\\
        741 11.234\\
        557 11.334\\
        388 11.434\\
        83  11.534\\
        -354    11.634\\
        -437    11.734\\
        116 11.834\\
        834 11.934\\
        1036    12.034\\
        932 12.134\\
        1037    12.234\\
        1276    12.334\\
        1196    12.434\\
        827 12.534\\
        497 12.634\\
        311 12.734\\
        380 12.834\\
        786 12.934\\
        1309    13.034\\
        1434    13.134\\
        895 13.234\\
        -19 13.334\\
        -1053   13.434\\
        -1955   13.534\\
        -2578   13.634\\
        -2503   13.734\\
        -1480   13.834\\
        409 13.934\\
        2791    14.034\\
        4626    14.134\\
        5186    14.234\\
        3729    14.334\\
        249 14.434\\
        -3340   14.534\\
        -5788   14.634\\
        -5890   14.734\\
        -4034   14.834\\
        -1627   14.934\\
        634 15.034\\
        2091    15.134\\
        2743    15.234\\
        2710    15.334\\
        2003    15.434\\
        643 15.534\\
        -682    15.634\\
        -1535   15.734\\
        -1510   15.834\\
        -915    15.934\\
        -359    16.034\\
        -376    16.134\\
        -992    16.234\\
        -1759   16.334\\
        -2045   16.434\\
        -1443   16.534\\
        -142    16.634\\
        1047    16.734\\
        1505    16.834\\
        1009    16.934\\
        -67 17.034\\
        -1116   17.134\\
        -1539   17.234\\
        -1325   17.334\\
        -848    17.434\\
        -469    17.534\\
        -373    17.634\\
        -387    17.734\\
        -339    17.834\\
        -263    17.934\\
        -384    18.034\\
        -769    18.134\\
        -1245   18.234\\
        -1511   18.334\\
        -1410   18.434\\
        -1015   18.534\\
        -604    18.634\\
        -419    18.734\\
        -506    18.834\\
        -583    18.934\\
        -462    19.034\\
        -67 19.134\\
        322 19.234\\
        434 19.334\\
        204 19.434\\
        -202    19.534\\
        -662    19.634\\
        -906    19.734\\
        -890    19.834\\
        -689    19.934\\
        -511    20.034\\
        -446    20.134\\
        -492    20.234\\
        -619    20.334\\
        -758    20.434\\
        -899    20.534\\
        -960    20.634\\
        -887    20.734\\
        -607    20.834\\
        -137    20.934\\
        327 21.034\\
        537 21.134\\
        346 21.234\\
        -151    21.334\\
        -671    21.434\\
        -1015   21.534\\
        -1079   21.634\\
        -920    21.734\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

What I don't understand is how I can add the arrows required and the text (that will be on a different colour - probably red but that's minor).

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does any of answers in [How to point an equation to a curve](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238985/how-to-point-an-equation-to-a-curve/238991#238991) serve to you?

Comment: this might do the work. I will try it out and give an update. Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this?